# me da error en "if( $stmt-> execute())" con PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando el modelo vista controlador, tengo un problema donde me larga error indicado en el título en la linea de:" if( $stmt-> execute()){", no me genera el Usuario en la BD y es lo que más me está molestando, adjunto el link de git por si alguien lo quiere ejecutar : 
https://github.com/gabrielaflores09/pos-muebles.git

coloco la parte del código código que lleva acabo para que puedan guiarme:

> Este es el código de la conexión a la BD

```
class Conexion{
  static public function conectar(){
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pos","root","");
    $link ->exec("set names utf8");
    return $link;
   }
}
```

> Este es el del controlador

```
class ControladorUsuarios{  static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

    if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

        if ( preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/", $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
             preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/", $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) && 
             preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $_POST["nuevaContraseña"])) {

            $tabla = "usuario";

            $datos = array("nombreUsuario" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                            "nickUsuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                            "contraseñaUsuario" => $_POST["nuevaContraseña"],
                            "perfilUsuario" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"]);

            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos);

             if($respuesta == "ok") {

                    echo '<script>
                    swal({
                    type: "success",
                    title: "¡Usuario guardado correctamente!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = "usuarios";
                        }   
                        });
                    </script>';
            }
            }else{

            echo '<script>
                swal({
                    type: "error",
                    title: "¡El Nombre o Usuario no puede ir vacio o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrars",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = "usuarios";
                        }   
                });

            </script>';
        }
    }
}
```

> Y esta última es la del modelo:

```
    require_once: "conexion.php"; class ModeloUsuarios{ static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO 
        $tabla(nombreUsuario, nickUsuario, contraseñaUsuario, perfilUsuario, fotoUsuario)
        VALUES (:nombreUsuario, :nickUsuario, :contraseñaUsuario, :perfilUsuario, :fotoUsuario)");

    $stmt-> bindParam(":nombreUsuario", $datos["nombreUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt-> bindParam(":nickUsuario", $datos["nickUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt-> bindParam(":contraseñaUsuario", $datos["contraseñaUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt-> bindParam(":perfilUsuario", $datos["perfilUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if( $stmt-> execute() ){
        return "ok";
    }else{
        return "error";
    }
    $stmt -> close();
    $stmt = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Veo que tienes 5 parametros, pero solo estas bindeando 4.  Te falta `:fotoUsuario`

Comment: Hola, queria borrar fotoUsuario antes de subir la pregunta acá, pero se ve q me olvidé borrarla en esa parte... de todas formas ese no es el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está aquí...

```
$stmt-> bindParam(":contraseñaUsuario", $datos["contraseñaUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Nunca uses Ñ (tampoco tilde u otro carácter especial) en tu código... o te va a dar muchos dolores de cabeza... la Ñ solo para el usuario final, intenta usar el Inglés, en lugar de contraseña usa pass o password.

Usa este trozo de código en lugar del que tienes.

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO 
        $tabla( nombreUsuario, nickUsuario, contraseñaUsuario, perfilUsuario)
        VALUES (:nombreUsuario, :nickUsuario, :pass, :perfilUsuario)");

    $stmt-> bindParam(":nombreUsuario", $datos["nombreUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt-> bindParam(":nickUsuario", $datos["nickUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt-> bindParam(":pass", $datos["contraseñaUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt-> bindParam(":perfilUsuario", $datos["perfilUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: haber, primero le dices que nunca use `Ñ` pero en el código que le dices que use tu mismo vuelves a usar la `Ñ` entonces? ya no entendí debe o no debe usarlo

Comment: Yo le arreglé la parte del código que le da el error, las otras Ñ que usó no le dan problemas. Mi recomendación es que no las use nunca, con lo cual debería cambiar su código. Repito, yo solo le quité la Ñ que la daba el error.

Comment: y como llegaste a la conclusión de que ese es el error?

Comment: el error de hecho es donde va a dar de alta 5 datos, pero solo manda 4

Comment: Porque bajé el código de github y lo probé en mi ordenador, al cambiar la linea de código con la Ñ funcionó...

Comment: y como hiciste funcionar ese código, teniendo un valor que hace falta en la consulta, por favor comparte ese dato

Comment: además tu argumento debe ser mas sólido que solo decir lo bajé y lo probé

Comment: Pues un argumento más solido, no tengo,,, lo bajé y estuve probando varias opciones en busca del error hasta que quité las ñ y funcionó....

Comment: igual lo q mando 5 datos es verdad, pero ese no era el problema,... ya que habia decidido sacarlo antes de subir la pregunta.. pero se ve q me olvidé en una parte..

Comment: pruebo tu comentario y comento el resultado :)

Comment: Ripupo88  muchisimas gracias!! ese era el error!! jaja pensaba cambiar la 'ñ' pero x suponer q ese no era el problema nunca lo hice... te lo re agradezco... a veces la primer opcion de problema descartada es realmente el problema.. eternamente agradecida :)